# Handling header dependencies with cmake

Tags: gcc, cmake

Let's say I have `main.cpp`, `a.h` and `b.h` in the same folder. `main.cpp` includes `a.h`, and `a.h` includes `b.h`.

Checking the `generated depends.make` file, `main.cpp.o` depends both on `a.h` and `b.h`, as expected.

If `b.h` is moved to a folder `B`, and used the `-iquote B` flag, `main.cpp.o` does not depend any more on `b.h`.

I can put back the dependency by adding `include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/B)` to the `CMakeLists.txt` file. This however has a side effect: when compiling `main.cpp`, `cmake` uses the flag `-I/pathTo/B`. I prefer using `-iquote` instead of `-I`.

Is there a way in this second case to let `cmake` to detect the dependencies automatically without introducing the `-I` compiler flag?

Comment: The dependency checking is not done by CMake. The compiler will detect/track/output header dependencies. Just e.g. `-MMD` flags are added by CMake to the compiler call (see e.g. `CMAKE_DEPFILE_FLAGS_CXX`). I'm not sure if it would help the generally change `CMAKE_INCLUDE_FLAG_CXX` (which does define the `-I` flag). Or long story short: CMake does not support `-iquote` out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this SO answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899919/5820799

It boils down to not use `include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/B)`, but to manually add the `-iquote` directive instead:

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -iquote ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/B")`

This will generate `-iquote <path>` instead of `-I <path>`.
It is not pretty, but does the job. :-)