# target_include_directories(BEFORE) not working

Tags: c++, cmake

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898643/cmake-include-directories-order-after-before) question, but with the following difference: I have a file `inc/Math.h` included with `target_include_directories(tgt PUBLIC inc)`. But when include it, it includes the system header instead of my `Math.h`. It is possible to change this without renaming the header? I also tried `BEFORE` and it didn't worked.

```
// CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(PineapplePizza)

add_executable(NicolasCage main.cpp)
target_include_directories(NicolasCage inc)
```

```
// main.cpp
#include "Math.h" // Includes system's one, not inc/Math.h

int main() {}
```

```
// inc/Math.h
#pragma once

#include <cmath>
```

Comment: If you change `#include "Math.h"` to `#include "inc/Math.h"` it will likely solve the problem if the `inc` folder is in the same folder as `main.cpp` this way you don't have to worry about the order of include directories.

Comment: How about `target_include_directories(NicolasCage .)` and then `#include "inc/Math.h"`?

Comment: You see, you chose a pretty bad name for your header and apart from it being in the same folder as the files including it (and even that is not guaranteed), you hardly can do anything else if you want to use just `#include "Math.h"` on a case-insesitive FS.

Comment: I have some code to change because I developped on Linux, and the problem only appears on Windows because case-sensitive FS. So this is not possible. `#include "inc/***"` being very ugly, I will just create a subfolder `inc/NicolasCage` that acts like a namespace.